# How to read file without file input?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm developing an application in Javascript, which requires to read a text file and put it into a variable as input. However, I google many related questions and found that FileReader can't read file without file input because of security reason. Is there any library or dirty ways to read the content of a text file with only local path? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "found that FileReader can't read file without file input because of security reason" — This is your answer.

Comment: If you don't want to give file input , then hard code the file location in FileReader.

Comment: @ShakeerHussain What are you talking about? You can’t do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think a way to do it would be to load your file with Ajax. Then you can do whatever you want with its content.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // Do whatever you want here with this.responseText           
   }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "youtext.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to put your file.txt or file.json to your localhost, or put it on your server.

or this link maybe can help you out
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3227

i understand this question that he want to read file line by line from his local path.